# Usar una sola lista para varios forms en C#

Tags: c#, lista

Buen día expertos, estoy intentando utilizar una lista con cuatro propiedades que pueda ser accesada y modificada por dos forms diferentes. Los campos son los siguientes:

```
    public class Articulos
{
    public String articulo { get; set; }
    public int cantidadSolicitud { get; set; }
    public int cantidadTomada { get; set; }
    public String lote { get; set; }
}
```

Y la clase donde está la colección:

```
    public class ColeccionArticulos
{
    //La colección contendrá la lista de artículos de la solicitud
    public static List<Articulos> articulos;

    public ColeccionArticulos()
    {
        //Creamos una lista vacía
        articulos = new List<Articulos>();
    }

    //Se agrega un nuevo artículo a la lista
    public void agregarArticulo(Articulos nuevoArticulo)
    {
        articulos.Add(nuevoArticulo);
    }
}
```

En el form2 es donde creo la instancia:

```
    public partial class Lotes : Form
{
    public delegate void pasar(string dato);
    public event pasar pasado;
    Articulos a = new Articulos();
    ColeccionArticulos articulos = new ColeccionArticulos();
```

Y en un evento clic mando llamar la siguiente función:

```
public void ActualizarRegistro()
    {
        int loop = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridLotesDisponibles.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) != "")
                    {
                        a.articulo = lblArticulo.Text.ToString();
                        a.cantidadSolicitud = Int32.Parse(txtCantidadRequerida.Text.ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
                        a.cantidadTomada = Int32.Parse(gridLotesDisponibles.Rows[loop].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
                        a.lote = gridLotesDisponibles.Rows[loop].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                        ColeccionArticulos.articulos.Add(a);
                    }
            loop++;
        }
        pasado("Ventana generada por interfaz");
    }
```

Tengo dos problemas que no he conseguido resolver, el primero es que dentro de "artículos" sí se recorre el DGV, sin embargo, se almacenan únicamente los datos de la última fila, es decir, al recorrer el siguiente grid:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sólo se guarda tres veces lo de la última línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El segundo problema que tengo es que al cerrar la segunda ventana, oprimir "Seleccionar lotes" de otro producto y llenar la información de los lotes que le correspondan, se almacena nueva información pero siguiendo el ejemplo anterior, los 3 elementos que ya están creados se borran y no los deja almacenados.

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal en ambos puntos.
Solicito su apoyo para ver si pueden aconsejarme algo, orientarme, o sugerirme algún ejemplo o forma de resolverlo.

Gracias de antemano, saludos cordiales!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que revises esta implementación del modelo Singleton para asegurarte un correcto funcionamiento:

```
public class ColeccionArticulos
{
    private static ColeccionArticulos instance;

    public static ColeccionArticulos Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new ColeccionArticulos ();
            return instance; 
        }
    }
    //La colección contendrá la lista de artículos de la solicitud
    private List<Articulo> articulos;

    public ColeccionArticulos()
    {           
        nuevaLista ();
    }

    // Un método para iniciar una nueva lista cuando lo necesites.
    public void nuevaLista()
    {
        //Creamos una lista vacía
        articulos = new List<Articulo>();
    }

    //Se agrega un nuevo artículo a la lista
    public void agregarArticulo(Articulo nuevoArticulo)
    {
        articulos.Add(nuevoArticulo);
    }
}
```

Esto te permitirá usarlo de esta forma:

```
ColeccionArticulos.Instance.agregarArticulo ( unArticulo );
```

cuando necesites empezar con una lista nueva solo tienes que poner:

```
    ColeccionArticulos.Instance.nuevaLista();
```

y cuando necesites obtener los valores:

```
    Lista<Articulo> lista = ColeccionArticulos.Instance.getLista();
```

Importante! Revisa de crear un nuevo objeto antes de agregarlo a la lista.

Espero te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Hola buen día Leonardo, muchas gracias por tu sugerencia, lo implementé de esa forma y funcionó perfecto, como no tengo tanta experiencia programando, no lo puedo entender al 100%, pero funcionó de 10.

Comment: Que bueno. Un gusto haber ayudado! Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, el primer fallo que veo en tu código es que no creas un nuevo artículo cada vez que añades uno, estás reutilizando el artículo a, por lo que probablemente estas añadiendo 3 artículos con la misma referencia **(por eso se queda el valor del último articulo)**:

```
public void ActualizarRegistro()
    {
        int loop = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridLotesDisponibles.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) != "")
                    {
                        Articulos a = new Articulos(); //creando aquí cada artículo se solucionaría el problema
                        a.articulo = lblArticulo.Text.ToString();
                        a.cantidadSolicitud = Int32.Parse(txtCantidadRequerida.Text.ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
                        a.cantidadTomada = Int32.Parse(gridLotesDisponibles.Rows[loop].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
                        a.lote = gridLotesDisponibles.Rows[loop].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                        ColeccionArticulos.articulos.Add(a);
                    }
            loop++;
        }
        pasado("Ventana generada por interfaz");
    }
```

Probablemente ambos fallos tengan que ver con esto.

Comment: Hola que tal Daniel, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Agregué la línea que me recomendaste y efectivamente ya se guarda cada línea separada.
Sigo sin poder identificar porque se borra la lista cada que abro el segundo form y quiero agregar un nuevo elemento, sólo se guarda el último barrido del grid, tendrás alguna sugerencia?